# Blender modeling a mallet / T-joint with variable cylindrical dia

Tags: modeling, topology

Unlike regular T-Joint, mallet has shruken cylindrical component forged with a big cylindrical component.
Please guide correct mesh flow.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lobbx.jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the beginning you could duplicate your cylinder and use the copy as the *Target* of a *Shrinkwrap* modifier so that you're sure that the circular hole you'll dig will stick to the cylinder profile. Then apply the *Shrinkwrap* and extrude to make the handle.

[image]

Also, you could use much less polygons:

- Create a hole in the cylinder.
- Extrude and make a circle with *LoopTools > Circle*.
- In side view check that the circle's vertices are aligned with the cylinder profile (or use the shrinkwrap method if you think it's easier).
- Extrude again to make the handle.

[image]

Comment: Awesome @moonboots ! shrinkwrap helped greatly esp. the 24+12 vertices setup. tried box modeling with subd but shrinkwrap gave what wanted.

Comment: Here's a great video tutorial that shows the Shrinkwrap process that @moonboots describes.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ci1jBOm_5NY&t=1s